# Group cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $K$ be a number field, $p > 3$ a prime and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime of $K$ lying over $p$ and $n \geq 1$. Let $C$ be a subgroup of $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n)^\times$ and consider $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n$ as a $C$-module via multiplication. Let $C'$ be the prime-to-$p$ part of $C$.

How can I prove that $H^i(C',\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n) = 0$ for all $i$, arguing directly from the definitions (i.e with no high-powered (co)homological tools)?

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "high powered" ? There is a classical theorem in cohomology of groups which asserts that $H^{i}(G, A)=0$ for all $i$ if G is a finite group acting on a finite module A such that the orders of G and A are coprime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't come across this theorem in my literature search, can you possible provide a reference for it?

Comment: The "best" reference seems to be Serre's book "Local Fields", in the chapters devoted to group cohomology

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I am unable to find the theorem you stated in Serre's book, do you know the number of the Theorem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is corollary 1 of chapter 8 of the French edition (I suppose that the numbering is the same in the English edition). I recall that you wish to kill the cohomology of a finite group G acting on a finite module M. Your desire will be fulfilled by 2 facts:

-first, it follows trivially from the definition of cohomology via cocycles that for all $i\ge 1$, the groups $H^{i}$ are killed by the order of M

-second, using properties of the (co)restriction maps, the aforementioned corollary states that the $H^{i}$ are killed by the order of G

NB: we are dealing here with the ordinary cohomology groups, hence the requirement that $i\ge 1$. Since G is finite, we could as well replace them by the modified Tate cohomology groups and take all $i\in\mathbf Z$    ./.